# loading a simple angularjs jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

AngularJS won't show my transition in this jsfiddle

I've tried everything I can think of regarding setting this up

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL1pj284/1/)

```
main.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.25s ease all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

main.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-275px);
}
```

([it should work like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGFAF.gif))

[image]

This technically works locally but the this transition will never occur since I can't route to it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to review [ask] and [mcve] and then edit your question to help us help you.

Comment: you can use stackblitz instead of jsfiddle

Comment: `bootstrap.js` does not play well with `angular.js`

Comment: @georgeawg no kidding! I've spent two hours to try to get an example working, so that I can later spend more time fixing my poorly setup transition

Comment: The `ngRoute` documentation has an example that works on PLNKR. See [AngularJS $route Service API Reference - Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples)

Comment: @ram12393 I'm looking into it but that's a little tricky given the work I'm doing.

Comment: There are third party libraries that enable Bootstrap CSS to work with AngularJS. The most popular avoid loading `bootstrap.js` and its use of jQuery. The DOM manipulation of jQuery tends to fight the DOM manipulation of AngularJS.

Comment: @georgeawg interestingly, since i'm new to angularJS i've not dealt with any conflicts with DOM manipulation. This problem specifically began when I attempted to show an example that isn't local to my computer... I figured this isn't working because of my routing in the fiddle

Comment: Specifically `bootstrap.js` adds click handlers on `DOMContentLoaded`. When AngularJS directives such as `ng-view`, `ng-include`, `nr-repeat`, etc. add DOM, the new DOM does not get updated with `bootstrap.js` click handlers.

Comment: JSFiddle is not the right platform for creating examples of code that use ng-route. Start with the example on PLNKR that is supplied by the AngularJS team.